# Как переслать строку через интернет - C#

Tags: c#

Допустим на компьютере моего друга стоит программа-клиент которая должна пересылать строку на мой компьютер, где установлена программа-сервер. Пробовал через удаленный вызов методов с общей сборкой, но это не то. С помощью клиента-сервера на сокетах пытался, но так и не смог разобраться. Никак не могу понять в чем проблема. Пожалуйста, подскажите как это реализовать.

Comment: добавь пример того как пытался и что именно не получилось

Comment: Ссылки на сторонние ресурсы тут не приветствуются, поэтому предлагаю вбить в гугл: "клиент-серверное приложение на потоковом сокете tcp", вы сможете найти статью, в которой рассказано как создать сервер и клиента, а так же как передать между ними информацию.

Comment: Надо понимать находятся ли компьютер вашего друга и ваш в одной подсети. Если оба компьютера находятся не в "внешнем интернете" и даже не в "единой" локальной сети - то ответ *ничего не получится*. Надо что б как минимум ping пробрасывал от вас к вашему "другу".

Comment: @Geslot кто это вам сказал, что ссылки на сторонние ресурсы не приветствуются? Я ответил, так как считаю правильным. Передавать текст по сети предпочтительнее по http протоколу. Объекты на С#, с помощью которых это можно реализовать, написаны разработчиками microsoft. Вы предлагаете тут просто продублировать их код?

Comment: @Geslot Не приветствуются ссылки вместо ответов. А ссылка на официальную документацию с пояснением зачем она приведена - абсолютно нормальный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Не минусую вопрос, а предлагаю разобраться в том что такое http протокол, HttpListner, WebRequest. Вот ссылка на msdn про [listner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx), класс [webrequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx). Вам нужно отправить запрос(Можно 'GET', это тип запроса) с клиента (можно использовать класс webrequest), на стороне сервера принять запрос используя httplistner. Все примеры есть на msdn.